# MySQL replication, how to know what is updated?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

If I have 2 computers, A (master) and B (slave) how my application, depending on server B can know what is updated and when?

How do I get notified about an UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT statement **without** having direct access to the server A?

Comment: Maybe check out something like this, https://code.google.com/p/mysql-udf-http/ or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-12

Comment: Thanks, this is too complex for my needs, isn't there any other way?

Comment: Maybe you can look into triggers on database b; but I dont know if mysql features triggers.

Comment: It does feature such a basic feature. I will look at it, thanks!